# New blogs not being shown or stored in the database

Tags: php, laravel, controller, blogs

Once I delete a blog, it is deleted completely. I can make a new one, but it does not show on the website or in the database. This is my BlogController:

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use App\Models\Blog;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;

class BlogController extends Controller
{
    /**
     * Display a listing of the resource.
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
   
    public function index()
    {
        $blog = Blog::paginate(5);
        return view('blogs.index', compact('blog'))
            ->with('i',(request()->input('page',1)-1)*5);
    }

    /**
     * Show the form for creating a new resource.
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function create()
    {
        return view('blogs.create');
        
        Blog::create($request->all());
   
        return redirect()->route('blogs.index')
                        ->with('success','Blog created successfully.');
    }
  
    /**
     * Store a newly created resource in storage.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function store(Request $request)
    {
        $request->validate([
            'title' => 'required',
            'description' => 'required',
        ]);

        $blog = new Blog;
       
        $blog->title = $request->title;
 
        $blog->description = $request->description;

        $blog->save();
        
        return redirect()->route('blogs.index');

    }
   
    /**
     * Display the specified resource.
     *
     * @param  \App\Blog  $blog
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function show(Blog $blog)
    {
        return view('blogs.show', compact('blog'));
    }
   
    /**
     * Show the form for editing the specified resource.
     *
     * @param  \App\Blog  $blog
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function edit(Blog $blog)
    {
        return view('blogs.edit', compact('blog'));
    }
  
    /**
     * Update the specified resource in storage.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @param  \App\Blog  $blog
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function update(Request $request, Blog $blog)
    {
        $request->validate([
            'title' => 'required',
            'description' => 'required',
        ]);

        // $blog->title = $request->title;
 
       // $blog->description = $request->description;

        $blog->fill($request);
        
        // dd($blog);

        return redirect()->route('blogs.index')
                        ->with('success','Blog updated successfully');

    }
  
    /**
     * Remove the specified resource from storage.
     *
     * @param  \App\Blog  $blog
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function destroy(Blog $blog)
    {
        $blog->delete();
  
        return redirect()->route('blogs.index')
                        ->with('success','Blog deleted successfully');
    }
   

}
```

And the problem is apparently the 103th line, public function update:   `$blog->fill($request);` It does not store in the database nor is it visible on the webpage/blog. I tried deleting that specific line, but it is the same. Nothing changes. I do not understand what the issue could be. Can someone help?

Comment: `$blog->fill($request);` -> `$blog->fill($request->all());`

Answer (score 3):

**1ST OPTION** In order for the `fill` method to work, you must call `$blog->save()` after that.

```
$blog->fill($request); 
$blog->save();
```

Also when you use `fill` method you are mass assigning values. By default Laravel protects you from mass assigning fields.

Open your `Blog.php` model and add the fields you want to mass assign to the array `$fillable`

```
/**
 * The attributes that are mass assignable.
 *
 * @var array
 */
protected $fillable = [
    'title',
    'description',
];
```

**2ND OPTION** is to use the `update` method (don't forget to also add fields in `$fillable` in the model from 1st option since `update` method is also mass assigning fields):

```
$blog->update($request);
```

**3RD OPTION** manually assign each field one-by-one just like you did in the `store` method:

```
$blog->title = $request->title;
 
$blog->description = $request->description;

$blog->save();
```

Comment: Now I get the message "Missing required parameter for [Route: blogs.destroy] [URI: blogs/{blog}] [Missing parameter: blog]." This is my code: Route::delete('/blogs/destroy/{blog}', [BlogController::class, 'destroy'])->name('blogs.destroy');

Comment: I think that's a different problem from your original question. I think that error appears on your in one of your blade files. you must pass a parameter on your delete `route('blogs.destroy', [$blog->id])`. Can you include your view on your question. I'm just guessing here

Comment: BlogController: 
``` 
public function destroy(Blog $blog)
    {
        $blog->delete();
  
        return redirect()->route('blogs.index')
                        ->with('success','Blog deleted successfully');
    } 
```

Comment: I mean on your `blogs/index.blade.php` file, how are you calling the destroy blog route?

Comment: <td>
                <form action="{{ route('blogs.destroy',$blog->id) }}" method="POST">
   
                    <a class="btn btn-info" href="{{ route('blogs.show',$blog->id) }}">Show</a>
    
                    <a class="btn btn-primary" href="{{ route('blogs.edit',$blog->id) }}">Edit</a>
   
                    @csrf
                    @method('DELETE')
      
                    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-danger" href="{{ route('blogs.destroy',$blog->id) }}">Delete</button>
                </form>
            </td>

Comment: Seems correct. Maybe the error is triggering from another file. Like I said this is another problem from your question here.. Kindly post another question and put the complete details there.

Comment: it is not letting me ask another question because this one is not well received. you can head over to the laracasts and find me under "unknownana"

Answer (score 0):

The `fill` function dose not update data in database.

This function only assignment value to attribute in `protected $fillable = ['title','description'];` in Blog model.
Using `update` function to update data to database.

```
$blog->fill($request); 
$blog->update();
```